# RPM for a Python program: copy sources or install packages?

Tags: python, virtualenv, rpm

I'm developing a Python webserver. The target machine is a Red Hat Linux, so I have also to maintain the RPM creation.

Currently the RPM copies from the developing VM the python third party libraries that are needed by the program. The program daemon adds the target directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

My intention is instead to add the needed python packages to the RPM and install them in a virtualenv.

I also found these solutions:

1. using [python_sitearch](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Python). Not sure it's good to install them in the system
2. using [distutils](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/builtdist.html#creating-rpm-packages), but the project does not contains only python code, and, again, I suppose the packages will be installed in the system.

Comment: Would it not be better to have a `requirements.txt` file pinning the module choice and versions, and install that in the virtualenv? Or are there installation limitations in the target environment?

Comment: @SimonFraser yes, target can be without an internet connection, and could not have pip installed.